# Взаимодействие со сторонней консольной программой

Tags: python, python-3.x

Как написать программу, которая запускала бы стороннюю консольную программу, могла бы подавать туда команды, а также получать ответы?

```
output = subprocess.check_call(['komodo-13.01-64bit.exe'], shell=True)
```

Данный код позволяет запустить эту программу. Вопрос в том, как с ней после этого взаимодействовать именно программно?

Так в консоли Python появляется строка, в которую можно писать команды (только вручную, судя по всему) для `komodo-13.01-64bit.exe`, и даже будут приходить ответы, но все только визуально. Это никуда не записывается?

[Похожий вопрос был на Delphi](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/607549/delphi-xe-%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BE-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BC), но только у меня то не Delphi.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/14457303/5741205

Comment: Данный код не работает под python 3, даже не упоминая синтаксис, выдает ошибку "a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'"

Comment: После просмотра, я вот так переписал код
https://pastebin.com/LwwKidE2
Выдает "b'Komodo 13.01 64-bit (C) 2019 Don Dailey, Larry Kaufman and Mark Lefler\r\nusing hardware POPCNT\r\ninfo string Licensed to Fausto Monteiro Mesquita Junior\r\n'"
Без возможности дальнейшей работы с программой.

Comment: Я посмотрел внимательнее и обнаружил, что под Windows эта задача решается только с шаманским бубном и адскими костылями. :( Для Posix систем можно использовать модуль pexpect.

Comment: Не могли рассказать чуть подробнее про способ решения, если это использование костыля, то ок, если установка новой системы, тоже сойдет.
Очень уж охота написать эту программу (любыми методами), заранее спасибо.

Comment: поищите на англ. SO вопросы, где народ пытается совместить `subprocess.Popen` с `pyautogui` и там еще будут танцы с бубном, чтобы построчно читать из STDOUT и чтобы не завершился процес... В общем, очень все это муторно.

Comment: может это чем-то поможет https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1116602/234134

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться модулем [Pexpect](https://pexpect.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html). Начиная с вер. 4.0 добавлена (ограниченная) поддержка для Windows:

> As of version 4.0, Pexpect can be used on Windows and POSIX systems. However, `pexpect.spawn` and `pexpect.run()` are only available on POSIX, where the `pty` module is present in the standard library. See [Pexpect on Windows](https://pexpect.readthedocs.io/en/stable/overview.html#windows) for more information.

Небольшой пример:

```sql
>>> from pexpect.popen_spawn import PopenSpawn
>>> from pexpect import EOF,TIMEOUT
>>>
>>> p = PopenSpawn ('python -iu')
>>> p.expect (['>>> ', TIMEOUT, EOF], timeout=1)
0
>>> p.before.rstrip ().decode ()
'Python 3.8.3 (tags/v3.8.3:6f8c832, May 13 2020, 22:37:02) [MSC v.1924 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32\nType "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.'
>>> p.sendline ('1+2')
5
>>> p.expect (['>>> ', TIMEOUT, EOF], timeout=1)
0
>>> p.before.rstrip ().decode ()
'3'
>>> p.sendeof ()
>>> p.wait ()
0
```

Возможно также и с [subprocess.Popen](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#popen-objects), но будет несколько сложнее:

```sql
>>> from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT
>>>
>>> p = Popen (['python', '-iu'], stdout=PIPE, stdin=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT)
>>> p.stdout.readline ().rstrip ().decode ()
'Python 3.8.3 (tags/v3.8.3:6f8c832, May 13 2020, 22:37:02) [MSC v.1924 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32'
>>> p.stdout.readline ().rstrip ().decode ()
'Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.'
>>> p.stdin.write (b'1+2\n')
4
>>> p.stdin.flush ()
>>> p.stdout.readline ().rstrip ().decode ()
'>>> 3'
>>> p.stdin.close ()
>>> p.wait ()
0
```

Answer (score 1):

С subprocess.Popen вполне возможно реализовать. Не так просто, но все решаемо. Делал в одном проекте, но сейчас нет доступа к его исходникам.

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]