# Как посылать команду другой программе из программы на python

Tags: python, cmd

Есть программа которая запускается в консоли и туда можно посылать команды и она дает на них ответ.
Пример cmd -> '/program.exe' дальше ввожу команды .

Как мне взаимодействовать с этой программой из скрипта на python. мне нужно автоматизировать запуск , отправку команды и сохранить результат ответа.

Это возможно?

вот пример. я запускаю программу а потом отправляю комманду load_tree
[image: что нужно запустить]

Comment: subprocess посмотрите

Comment: subprocces позволяет вызвать программу но передать ЕЙ команды. не позволяет

Comment: покажите пример вашей программы

Comment: я загрузил пример в искомый вопрос.(сверху)

Comment: По описанию похоже на клиент/серверное взаимодействие.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

исходя из данного примера, вы можете решить свой вопрос

```
import subprocess


def run_win_cmd(command):
    result = []
    process = subprocess.Popen(command,
                               shell=True,
                               stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                               stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
   for line in process.stdout:
       result.append(line)
   errcode = process.returncode
   for line in result:
       print(line)
   if errcode is not None:
       raise Exception('cmd %s failed, see above for details', command)

run_win_cmd(input('введите команду: '))
```